# HTML+CSS table with vertical scrollbar but with a fixed header

Tags: html, css, header

Im making a website where I have quite some tables with big amount of data.
Therefor I decided to use scrollbars in the tables and that part works.
But now I want that te header where the title is in stays visible and don't disappear.

This is what I have so far:
[HTML+CSS+Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sT3cp.png)
The question is how can I set the header position fixed so when even u scroll down the header stay visible while the body dissapear.

Regards,

Html code

```
 <div class="tableFixHead">
  <table width="95%">
  <thead>
         <tr>
          <th><h1>LOG</h1>
          <br>
          <h2>datum tijd actuator waarde</h2> </th>
        </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
  <th scope= "col"><h1> <pre>{{ content }}</pre>  </h1>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>
```

css

```
.tableFixHead { 
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  max-height: 600px; 
} 

.tableFixHead table thead tr th { 
  position: sticky; 
  top: 0;
} 

table { 
  border-collapse: collapse; 
}
```

Comment: Hi. Please paste the html and css is here, or make a sandbox.

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov Hi, I placed html code of the table in the post. And the css in the post below cuz It wouldnt let met post it

Comment: CSS
    .mystyle {
  background-color: coral;
  color: white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
 .tableFixHead {
        overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden; 
        height: 600px;

      }
      .tableFixHead thead th {
        position: sticky;
        top: 0;
      }
      table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        
      }

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov Hi, thanks for your help! I only have one question about the sticky. I use the code u edited and when I scroll I get this.(see new pic in the post). How can I make the code invisible above the header –

Comment: See what's above the `thead` tag in the html code.

Comment: `"Trial"` - this is `thead`?

Comment: Thats the name of the table

Comment: Make a sandbox and show me all the code you did. Or paste all the code here.

Comment: CSS: <style>
.mystyle { 
  background-color: coral; 
  color: white; 
  box-sizing: border-box; 
} 

.tableFixHead { 
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  max-height: 600px; 
} 

.tableFixHead table thead tr th { 
  position: sticky; 
  top: 0;
} 

table { 
  border-collapse: collapse; 
}
</style>

Comment: no no ... need html table code

Comment: Yeahh sorry, I was pasting the html code of the table in the post cuz it was too long for here. The content code generates all the values of mine sensors

Comment: Can you paste your code here - jsfiddle.net? And give me a link.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=O0enQJ4O4m

Comment: I shared the whole html code and css, Most of the css isnt usefull for this part. There are also references of python and javascript for reading sensor values and actuators

Comment: Good. Let me give you time to get from work to home. Upon arrival home, I will open your problem and help you. Thank you.

Comment: Thankss a lot, I actually have a another question. How can I get a fixed position of tabels when I have like 8 tables on same page. I tried to use "<table style "margin-left: 5%"> but that is a lot of work when all tables must be placed. So is there like a piece of code that helps placing all tables at correct positions?

Comment: You can set a rule for all tables in one call - `selector table { margin-left: 5%; }` - did you mean that? And the sandbox doesn't work now - `jsfiddle.net`. I have a better idea. If your project is on the server, then you can give me a link to the site, and I will do everything through the browser object inspector.

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov Hi, tjsfiddle.net isnt working?  The project is sadly not on a server.

Comment: And I meant that I have many tables on a page and I want them to get a nice fixed positon. Cuz now there is a table a bit higer and more to the left. But I would like that the get a fixed postion on the page

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov Hi, is it maybe possible that u show me a html and css code how u would make a table with a scrollbar and a fixed header?

Comment: Hello. I'm sorry. I just read your question :(... Sorry. Is your problem still relevant?

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov Hi,well the table still scrolls behind the header. And no worries :). Beside that, do u also have experience how u can make a chart on html page with use of python values

Comment: My python practice is limited to university. I'm not good at working with python :(

Comment: @s.kuznetsov Hi I saw u have experience of  javascript, so are u maybe able to help me out how I can use javascript to read values from a txt file so i can make a chart of it??

Answer (score 0):

Your `table` body structure is incorrect. [Take a look here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/thead).

For stickiness, you need to add these rules for selector `.tableFixHead table thead tr th`:

```
.tableFixHead table thead tr th { 
  position: sticky; 
  top: 0;
}
```

Also, your `.mystyle` class is not used in your example. Perhaps this is only within the framework of this issue.

Also, pay attention here:

```
<table width = "90%";>
```

Remove the `;` character, or put it in quotes, after the value. As here:

```
<table width = "90%;">
```

```css
.mystyle { 
  background-color: coral; 
  color: white; 
  box-sizing: border-box; 
} 

.tableFixHead { 
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  max-height: 600px; 
} 

.tableFixHead table thead tr th { 
  position: sticky; 
  top: 0;
} 

table { 
  border-collapse: collapse; 
}
```

```html
<div class="tableFixHead">
<table width="90%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Active recipe 1</th>
      <th>Active recipe 2</th>
      <th>Active recipe 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>actuator </td>
      <td>Waarde </td>
      <td>eenheid </td>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
      <td>actuator </td>
      <td>Waarde </td>
      <td>eenheid </td>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
      <td>actuator </td>
      <td>Waarde </td>
      <td>eenheid </td>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
      <td>actuator </td>
      <td>Waarde </td>
      <td>eenheid </td>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
      <td>actuator </td>
      <td>Waarde </td>
      <td>eenheid </td>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
      <td>actuator </td>
      <td>Waarde </td>
      <td>eenheid </td>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
      <td>actuator </td>
      <td>Waarde </td>
      <td>eenheid </td>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
      <td>actuator </td>
      <td>Waarde </td>
      <td>eenheid </td>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
      <td>actuator </td>
      <td>Waarde </td>
      <td>eenheid </td>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
      <td>actuator </td>
      <td>Waarde </td>
      <td>eenheid </td>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
      <td>actuator </td>
      <td>Waarde </td>
      <td>eenheid </td>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
      <td>actuator </td>
      <td>Waarde </td>
      <td>eenheid </td>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
      <td>actuator </td>
      <td>Waarde </td>
      <td>eenheid </td>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
      <td>actuator </td>
      <td>Waarde </td>
      <td>eenheid </td>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
      <td>actuator </td>
      <td>Waarde </td>
      <td>eenheid </td>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
      <td>actuator </td>
      <td>Waarde </td>
      <td>eenheid </td>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
      <td>actuator </td>
      <td>Waarde </td>
      <td>eenheid </td>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
      <td>actuator </td>
      <td>Waarde </td>
      <td>eenheid </td>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
      <td>actuator </td>
      <td>Waarde </td>
      <td>eenheid </td>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
      <td>actuator </td>
      <td>Waarde </td>
      <td>eenheid </td>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
      <td>actuator </td>
      <td>Waarde </td>
      <td>eenheid </td>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
      <td>actuator </td>
      <td>Waarde </td>
      <td>eenheid </td>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
      <td>actuator </td>
      <td>Waarde </td>
      <td>eenheid </td>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
      <td>actuator </td>
      <td>Waarde </td>
      <td>eenheid </td>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
      <td>actuator </td>
      <td>Waarde </td>
      <td>eenheid </td>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
      <td>actuator </td>
      <td>Waarde </td>
      <td>eenheid </td>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
      <td>actuator </td>
      <td>Waarde </td>
      <td>eenheid </td>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
      <td>actuator </td>
      <td>Waarde </td>
      <td>eenheid </td>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
      <td>actuator </td>
      <td>Waarde </td>
      <td>eenheid </td>
    </tr>   
   <tr>
      <td>actuator </td>
      <td>Waarde </td>
      <td>eenheid </td>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
      <td>actuator </td>
      <td>Waarde </td>
      <td>eenheid </td>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
      <td>actuator </td>
      <td>Waarde </td>
      <td>eenheid </td>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
      <td>actuator </td>
      <td>Waarde </td>
      <td>eenheid </td>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
      <td>actuator </td>
      <td>Waarde </td>
      <td>eenheid </td>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
      <td>actuator </td>
      <td>Waarde </td>
      <td>eenheid </td>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
      <td>actuator </td>
      <td>Waarde </td>
      <td>eenheid </td>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
      <td>actuator </td>
      <td>Waarde </td>
      <td>eenheid </td>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
      <td>actuator </td>
      <td>Waarde </td>
      <td>eenheid </td>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
      <td>actuator </td>
      <td>Waarde </td>
      <td>eenheid </td>
    </tr>   
  </tbody>
</table>    
</div>
```